# Nested Tree with Parent Id from same JSON using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, recursion

I am attempting to create a nested tree of sorts using Reactjs.

- Parent

  - Child

My JSON looks something like this

```
[{
    id: 45,
    parentId: 0;
},
{
    id: 49,
    parentId: 45;
}]
```

My thought was to create a TreeLevel and have a click handler on each `<li>`. If there are children, it would then append that `<ul>` to the `<li>`

```
//Here is my component call
<TreeLevel pId={pId} treeData={treeData} /> 

//-- component
const TreeLevel = (props) => {
    const temp = props.treeData.filter(tree => {
         return tree.parentId === props.pId;
    });

    const lis = temp.map((li, index) => {
        return (
            <li key={index} onClick={() => showChildren(li.id, props.treeData)}>
                {li.name}

            </li>
        );
    });

    return <ul>{lis}</ul>
}

function showChildren(pId, treeData) {
    // this doesn't work, but the idea of what I want it to do
    return ( <TreeLevel pId={pId} treeData={treeData} />);
}

class Tree extends Component {
    render() {
        const { treeData, pId } = this.props;

        return (
                <TreeLevel pId={pId} treeData={treeData} />
        );
    }
}
```

And here is my main call from the App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        parentId: 0,
        treeData: [ // array of objects here
        ]
    };

  render() {
    const { treeData, pId } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Tree treeData={treeData} pId={parentId} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I can get the first level (parentId = 0), but when I tried to put a **click event** on each of the `<li>` tags, I don't know how to **append the HTML** from the `TreeLevel` component to the DOM, let alone in the correct location.

I was using the following tutorial as a loose guide. [React Tutorial](https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/)

Any thoughts?

Comment: are you using `ReactDOM.render` function to render `TreeLevel` component ?

Comment: I have the component being called from the render function in the App.js file.

Comment: can you add your  full App.js here as well ?

Comment: I updated with my call from App.js. It displays the main level `<ul>` it's just the recurision and nesting that I am having problems with.

Comment: what exactly do you want `showChildren` to do here ?

Comment: I forgot to post it. I put it in the code above. The idea is that when I click on an `li`, if that id has children, then the TreeLevel component will run again and the new `ul` will be inserted/appended to the `li` I just clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185029/discussion-between-pranay-tripathi-and-zombiecode).

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I also just started with ReactJS. But I hope to help you out. So assume that my advice and code isn't 100% correct.

A `Component` should always be a `Class`.

In the `render()` function you can write down code (and JSX). But only render one main element. If you have multiple items, push their JSX in an array. And render that `{array}` later.

```
import React { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class TreeLevel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const temp = this.props.treeData.filter(tree => {
            return tree.parentId === props.pId;
        });

        let liArray = [];

        const lis = temp.map((li, index) => {
            liArray.push(
                <li key={index} onClick={() => showChildren(li.id, props.treeData)}>
                    {li.name}
                </li>
            );
        });

        return (
            <ul>
                {liArray}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TreeLevel pId={pId} treeData={treeData} />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Your `showChildren` function should also go in the class `TreeLevel`. And can be referred to with `this.showChildren()`.

However, I think you got the fundamentals wrong. My advice would be to first read the documentation through. I also don't 100% get it yet, but I think it's slowly starting to click.

Comment: I was basing my const variable off of this tutorial, where the table rows were used like I did for the `li` https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/

Comment: It looks like you just have to `ReactDOM.render()` your `Tree` `Component` like my last line of code.